# Why does the identity matrix times another matrix yield a third matrix?

Tags: matrices, python

From what I learned, multiplying any matrix with the Identity Matrix of Multiplication results in the same matrix again. [Here](http://www.sparknotes.com/math/algebra2/matrices/section3.rhtml#identity_matrix)'s also an example of this. I've tried the following in NumPy:

```
>>> m = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, -1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]], float)
>>> m
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
>>> np.identity(4)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> np.identity(4) * m
```

I would expect the result of the last line to be the same as `m`, but it's not.

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

What about the "Identity Matrix" statement, that any matrix multiplied with a compatible identity matrix (or the other way round) results in the same matrix?

Comment: Your result would make sense if the `*` operator you're applying doesn't actually implement matrix multiplication but just multiplies the elements of the two arrays one position at a time. How sure are you that `*` is supposed to be matrix multiplication in this context?

Comment: Ohhhh K, that's embaressing.. You're right, it appears to be just element-wise multiplication. There is `np.matmul()`. Thanks